# How to join three tables with to avoid invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

Having three tables as follows

```
Table 1
c_id   User_id    code
-------------------------
001       UI1      AB01
002       UI2      XD01
003       UI3      AD01
004       UI4      OP01
005       UI5      QW01
```

```
Table 2
id    c_id    brn_code      sts
-----------------------------------
1     004     90E1           Y
2     005     91E3           Y
3     001     91S4           Y
4     003     93S6           Y
5     002     99S7           Y
```

```
Table 3
Key      brn_code
--------------------
1         91S4
2         90D1
3         90Z5
4         93S6
5         96W4
```

Need Output like below

```
INSERT INTO table2 t2 (c_id, brn_code, sts)VALUES ('004', '90D1', 'Y');
INSERT INTO table2 t2 (c_id, brn_code, sts)VALUES ('004', '90Z5', 'Y');
INSERT INTO table2 t2 (c_id, brn_code, sts)VALUES ('004', '96W4', 'Y');
```

Wrote query as

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO table2 t2 (c_id, brn_code, sts)VALUES ('||t1.c_id||', '||t3.brn_code||', '||''''||'Y'||''''||');'
FROM Table 1 t1 JOIN Table 2 t2
ON t1.c_id = t2.c_id JOIN 
(SELECT brn_code FROM Table 3 t3 
MINUS
(SELECT brn_code FROM Table 2 t2
WHERE t2.c_id IN (SELECT t1.c_id FROM Table 1 t1 WHERE t1.User_id = 'UI4' AND t1.code = 'OP01')
AND t2.sts = 'Y')) ON t2.brn_code = t3.brn_code;
```

For above query i returns error as `invalid identifier`. I don't know why this error came.
How to get output as above.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement. It is not obvious.

Comment: because you didn't alias the subquery with `t3` just before `ON t2.brn_code = t3.brn_code`, but in any case how do you think of producing three row values of `004` for `table1.c_id`  ?

Comment: @GMB I want exact insert script that i mentioned. I want to pick brn_code from Table3 that is not present in Table2.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wrote `Table 1 t1` etc., that's certainly wrong. Should probably be something like `Table1` if your tables are called as suggested in your first line.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with names of the table as already mentioned in the other answer.

Also, you can simplify your query by using `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO table2 t2 (c_id, brn_code, sts)VALUES ('||t1.c_id||', '||t3.brn_code||', '||''''||'Y'||''''||');'
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.c_id = t2.c_id 
JOIN table3 t3 on t2.brn_code = t3.brn_code
Where not exists ( 
  Select 1 from table2 t22 join table1 t11 on t11.c_id = t22.c_id
   Where t11.User_id = 'UI4' AND t11.code = 'OP01' AND t22.sts = 'Y' And t3.brn_code = t22.brn_code);
```

Comment: Given select statement not worked. I want the exact result that i mentioned. But it never works.